# Change the rows based on the neighbors rows in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which only contains 0 and zeros. I wnat to change the df with this way:
I move with a sliding window of 4 through the columns and all rows. for example, the first window is df.iloc[:, 0:4] and if we dont have any 1 in this window,
we dont change anything in this. But if we have 1 in this window, only the rows that has 1 changed to 1. For example, for window 1, id=2 has 1, so for row id=2,
column 0:4 change to 1, and also same for row id=3. I provide a df here, and also the desired output.

I can do this with a loop over the df, however, my df has millions rows and it takes time with my inefficient way.
Can you please help me with that? thanks.

here is the df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Ids'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['a1'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a2'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['a3'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['a4'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['a5'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a6'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['a7'] = [1, 0, 1]
df['a8'] = [1, 0, 1]
df['a9'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a10'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a11'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a12'] = [0, 0, 0]
```

and here is the output:

```
   Ids  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10  a11  a12
0    1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0    0    0    0
1    2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
2    3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html) on the reversed array after temporarily setting Ids as index:

```
out = (df.set_index('Ids', append=True).loc[:, ::-1]
         .rolling(3, axis=1, min_periods=1).max()
         .astype(int).reset_index('Ids')[df.columns]
      )
```

Or using a 2D convolution with [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html):

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

N = 3
cols = df.columns[1:]

df[cols] = convolve2d(df[cols], np.r_[np.ones(N, dtype=bool),
                                      np.zeros(N-1, dtype=bool)].reshape(1, -1),
                      mode='same').astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Ids  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10  a11  a12
0    1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0    0    0    0
1    2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
2    3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you. This one create 5 of 1 (not 4) in row one. The other parts is ok.

Comment: I see, it looks like you want a window of 3, not 4. Please clarify the logic in the question and break down the calculation for a few values.